# Keyboard map changed after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have Logitech G510s keyboard. It has additional keys G1-G18.

In 20.04 they were mapped as F1-F12 + 1-6.

In 22.04, `keycodes/event` are extended and contains mapping of these keys (G1 scan code 656) as `KEY_MACRO1` with comment `Key codes below cannot be used in X`

How can I get back previous mapping?
Or how can I make these keys visible in X?

Answer (score 0):

Found workaround (or possible bug?)

- after boot, it doesn't work
- after suspend-resume, it starts to work
- after unplug-plug, it stops working again